# ibm connections adding a library to comunity

Tags: widget, ibm-connections

Im trying to make connections 4.5 working with content manager. I guess im quite far away from start finally but there are many things i need to fix.

1. Sometimes my widgets just doesnt load. It says cannot load widgets-config.xml

   - when i restart deployment and appsrv everything looks good.
2. My biggest problem is to add library to community. Because i want to see how workflow works and the id like to create linked library of this. This is what i get when i try to add library widget to the community (linked library widget works well)

   ```
   CLFWZ0004E: Event 'widget.added' sent to remote lifecycle handler at https://conserv.egroup.local/dm/atom/communities/feed returned bad response: 403 - Forbidden
   ```

I guess there is som problem with https access. Can anybody of you guys ever faced this problem? Some hints?

**UPDATE-1**

After accessing that page from it gives me this :

```
 <td:error>
   <td:errorCode>UnsupportedOperation</td:errorCode>
   <td:errorMessage>CQL5602:  The attempted operation, GET, is not allowed on the resource /communities/feed.  
                    Contact your administrator and provide the incident ID:  1381320497551.  
                    The administrator should forward this information to the application owner.
   </td:errorMessage>
 </td:error>
```

So i guess maybe there can be som problem with proxy policies. I tried to make some changes with changes default policy url to *. But still no progress..

Hints?

Comment: if it can't load the widgets-config.xml I'd run a diff to see what is different in the widgets-config

Comment: I dont understand a bit. Can u explain it more complex please?

Comment: check your deployment manager's widgets-config.xml and check your appsrv's widgets-config.xml sounds like you may have edited the appsrv, and it might be changed... just compare the files

Comment: yeah. I think i changed also appsrvs config. appsrv's widget-config should not be changed?

Comment: Ok. I changed back what i modified - comment custom library - but now im not able to use linkedlibrary and Library problem is still there. Any other guess? I tried to change something in proxy-config but still no change. Maybe it is something with it becasue when i try to access **https://conserv.egroup.local/dm/atom/communities/feed** it gives me error ( POSTED IN UPDATE)

Comment: I read something that you need to apply a role to get it to work. I think it's in one of this guys Slideshare  http://www.slideshare.net/FrankAltenburg/ibm-connections-45-installation-from-zero-to-social-hero-201-with-domino-ldap